# How to clear terminal in Visual studio code since last update?

Tags: visual-studio

how to clear the terminal in visual studio code?
Yesterday i have installed the last update and now ctrl+k is not working anymore.

Comment: Typing the command `clear` doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open command Palette `Ctr+Shift+P` and type `Terminal: Clear` to clear the terminal
in the right hand side you will see the shortcut

[image: clear terminal shortcut]

[edit]

its look like in new update of vs code remove the shortkart key to clear the terminal.

but you can re-enable the shortkart by gooing to `File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortkart` and search `terminal.clear` and press the plus/edit button

[image]

and then add the prefered shortkart key

Comment: Thank you my friend. I was realy pissed.